# DSS boxcarring and request_box

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I am facing a problem in DSS boxcarring.

I enabled boxcarring in DSS and wrote queries for selecting data from three tables separately and inserting them in another three tables. When I try using it and click on `begin_boxcar` then my three operations and then `end_boxcar` it works well. An operation (`request_boxcar`) is created automatically and contains my three operations in order. When I click on it on try it, it works and my operations was run but when I use task schedule and select `request_box` I encounter an error. I use it with my endpoint in my browser but it doesn't work. How can I fix that?

```
http://IP:Port/services/Test/request_box
```

This is the error I encountered:

```
 type Exception report message description The server encountered an
 internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
 exception org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doGet(CarbonServlet.java:155)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
 root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.buildsoapMessage(BuilderUtil.java:148)
    org.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder.processDocument(XFormURLEncodedBuilder.java:118)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:188)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:146)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:116)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:843)
    org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.handleRestRequest(CarbonServlet.java:303)
    org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doGet(CarbonServlet.java:152)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
 Tomcat/7.0.59 logs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This is because, it fails to retrieve the incoming message when it is called by a dataservice task. I have created a JIRA which you can find from [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1207). You can track the progress from there, and it will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration